# My radio and audio output keep changing using WSJTX on FT8

Tags: audio-interface, wsjt-x

TL;DR  Laptop keeps switching between Signal Link audio output and speakers. Problem goes away when I turn TX knob down far enough on Signal Link.

I just bought a SignalLink and have it connected between my laptop and my radio (a Yaesu FT-450D). I've successfully made a couple QSO's on FT8, but keep running in to a problem.

When I tune the tx knob too high, the computer seems to change the audio output from the Signal Link back to the speakers on the laptop. As a result, the Signal Link doesn't get an audio signal any more and it turns off the PTT. After a moment (well less than a second), audio switches back to the Signal Link.

I can avoid the problem by keeping the TX knob turned way down, but them my actual transmitted power is way lower than intended.

Details:
Radio: Yaesu FT-450D
Laptop: old Dell running Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: The latest WSJT-X FT4 software has a bug that messes with the audio levels. If you are using the FT4 compatible software, I suggest you use the earlier released version.

Comment: I will try that. What's odd is that I don't have the problem testing with PSK31 in FLDigi or when using the Tune button in WSJT-X.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, unfortunately you can't power the interface externally because the USB both powers the tnc and is the data link. I have a power meter in line between my 706mkiig and antenna, with the volume mixer open, I can get up to about 75% volume on output(tx), anymore than that causes the tx to go into an on/off cycle, after a few seconds the mixer drops the volume down to 6%. Because of this, I can only output 75% power when transmitting.

Comment: @user152695 welcome to the amateur radio stack!  You might benefit from reviewing the tour here: https://ham.stackexchange.com/tour Please do not post additional questions or "I have this problem too" notes as answers to questions.  Thank you and welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the failure modes of SignaLink devices, but in general, a USB device disappearing temporarily likely means that its internal microprocessor or USB interface chip has been reset, or the USB connection itself failed.

The obvious hypothesis, then, is that your transmitted RF power is itself causing the problem by interfering with the digital electronics when it gets too high.

To collect evidence for whether or not this is true:

1. Check if the radio's transmit power setting also changes whether or not the problem occurs.
2. Make a *manual* transmission using your radio's own controls, not the computer (using CW or AM, not SSB, so that you don't need to change microphone connections to get any output power). If you observe your computer switching audio devices in the same way, this shows that the problem is triggered by the radio and not by the SignaLink unit.

If this is the case, then solutions depend on how the problematic RF is getting in. That can be difficult to measure, so practically it's a matter of trying fixes in whatever order is convenient:

- Problem: The transmitted power from the antenna is too high.
  Solution: Relocate your antenna farther from the rest of your station.
- Problem: The antenna is putting common-mode current onto the feed line.
  Solution: Ensure that it is fed properly (e.g. a dipole antenna fed by coax **must** have a balun).
- Problem: The transmitter is leaking RF onto its audio/control cables.
  Solution: Add ferrites to the cables between the radio and the SignaLink.

Comment: Also, if you can by any means, try switching out the USB cable and try using another USB port. If the device is powered via USB, but can also be powered through an external plug, try that.

Comment: This happened to me (radio interfering with usb).  I fixed it by wrapping the usb cable 4 times around a #43 toroid.  Alternately, they make usb cables with ferrite chokes built in.

Comment: I've checked item 1. Bumping power up on the radio allows a higher setting on the TX knob on the Signal Link. I would have expected the reverse. I'll try to test number 2 in the next couple days.

Comment: I’ve confirmed that it is related to transmit power. Anything over 10W will definitely make it cut out. Seems to vary between 5 and 10. Still working on the source.